# Deploy warning calling external JS function in `serverless.yml`

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

So, in my `serverless.yml` file I have this:

```yaml
custom:
  my_attr: ${file(./serverless/get-custom-value.js):my_attr}
```

And in that file (located in `./serverless/get-custom-value.js`) is this JavaScript code:

```js
module.exports.my_attr = async function(slsArg) {
  const stage = slsArg.providers.aws.getStage()
  console.debug(`### stage: "${stage}".`)
  return stage
}
```

When doing a `sls package -s {stage}` or `sls deploy -s {stage}` (which are both successful), I see this warning:

```
Serverless: Deprecation warning: Variables resolver reports following resolution errors:
              - Cannot resolve variable at "custom.my_attr": Cannot resolve "my_attr" out of "get-custom-value.js": Resolved a JS function not confirmed to work with a new parser, falling back to old resolver
```

Yet, despite the warning it works exactly as expected…

Answer (score 1):

It's a deprecation warning, which serves to inform you that in the next version of the Serverless Framework, this specific resolver syntax is deprecated (and will error) as internally the process for resolving variables has changed.

You can adopt the new custom resolver very simply by changing the declaration in the `serverless.yml` and modifying the function arguments in `get-custom-value.js`, then you can set

```
variablesResolutionMode: 20210326
```

in your `serverless.yml` to indicate you have migrated. That will instruct the Serverless Framework to use the new resolver, as indicated by the warning message.

The full overview is in the [documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#with-a-new-variables-resolver)